# Matchmaking Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science, combinatorics, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to figure out how to best match a borrower to a lender for a real estate transaction. Let’s say there’s a network of a 1000 lenders on a platform. A borrower would log in, and be asked to provide the following:

1. Personal Information and Track Record (how many projects they have done, credit score, net worth etc.)
2. Loan Information (loan size, type, leverage etc.)
3. Project Information (number of units, floors, location, building type etc.)

On the other side, a lender would provide criteria on which they would agree to lend on. For example, a lender agrees to lend to a borrower if:

1. They have done more than 5 projects
2. Credit Score > 700
3. Net Worth > Loan Amount
4. $500,000 < Loan Amount < $5,000,000
5. Leverage < 75%
6. Building Size > 10 Units
7. Location = CA, AZ, NY, CO
8. etc...

I want to create a system that matches a lender to a borrower based on the information the borrower provided and the criteria the lender provided. Ideally, the system would assign a 1000 scores to the borrower that represent the “matchmaking” score for each lender on the platform. A borrower that meets more of the lender’s lending requirements would get a higher score since the match should be better. What machine learning algorithm would be best suited to generate such a score? Or would this problem be solved using combinatorial optimization?

Thanks!

Comment: Research the stable marriage problem. This is a bipartite graph matching problem with some sugar on top.

Comment: @AndyG I fail to see how you get from, "How do I come up with a matchmaking score?" to, "This is a bipartite graph matching problem."  It can't be a graph matching problem until you have a way to estimate how good the match is.  Which is what the matchmaking score is for.  Furthermore even if he had a matchmaking score, it **still** is unlikely to be a bipartite graph matching problem.  Are all of the borrowers available up front?  Can you recommend the same lender to multiple borrowers?  The likely answers of "No" and "Yes" would make it not a bipartite graph matching problem.

Comment: @btilly ultimately OP wants to perform a matching of borrowers to lenders.  In a proper stable matching you would not match the same lender to multiple borrowers, but the more generic problem, the assignment problem, does allow for this. The marriage problem is a good starting point. The "sugar" on top would consist of all the other things about this specific problem, which IMO would require quite a bit of tweaking on the solver.

Comment: @AndyG You are addressing the trivial part of the problem, while dismissing the question actually asked as "sugar on top".  Namely, if nothing is a perfect fit, then how do we decide which matches are most likely to work out?  I've personally seen this kind of problem come up multiple times while working on affiliate websites, and have repeatedly seen programmers be told to solve it with machine learning.

Comment: In general if you have a matching rule, it is trivial to write code to pick the top `n`.  If your site gets scale, the trick is to find ways to filter out rows in the database to limit how much heavy-weight processing you do.  In neither case have I seen it be useful to think of it as a graph theory problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the system yet, you are unlikely to have good data for machine learning.

So write a few custom rules and start collecting data.  Once you have data, do something like build a logistic regression for estimating the probability of acceptance.  Once the model is good enough to beat your home grown rules in an A/B test, switch to the machine learning model.

But you can't invoke the magic of machine learning until you have data to learn from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So a good approach would be to build a rules engine to match borrowers and lenders. Once the system is up and running, we can create a training set to invoke the magic of machine learning. In your comment above, you mention that  it be useful to think of it as a graph theory problem. Can you please elaborate how that would be different than deploying a rules based engine?

Comment: @JurgendeJager Exactly right on the rules engine.  Also I said above that it isn't useful to think of it as a graph theory problem.  So that is not a recommend.